# How do I add sections side by side in a well panel?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to create a `wellPanel` to hold some inputs in a `shiny` app. The code below reproduces what I'm trying to do. However, I want `Section 2` to be right next to `Section 1` and not on the opposite side of the well (see screenshot).

[image]

How can I achieve this? See reprex below.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Basic Shiny App"),
    
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions
    fluidRow(
        column(
            width = 10, offset = 1,
            wellPanel(
                div(actionButton("toggle", "Toggle")),
                hr(),
                div(
                    id = "some_id",
                    div(
                        style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between;",
                        div(
                            style = "flex: 0.2; padding: 5px; background-color: wheat;",
                            div(
                                p("Section 1"),
                                actionButton("id", "Action 1")
                            )
                        ),
                        div(
                            style = "flex: 0.2; padding: 5px; background-color: pink;",
                            class = "pull-left",
                            div(
                                p("Sectino 2"),
                                actionButton("ids", "Action 2")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
 
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I also noticed that columns don't work well inside well panels. Especially if I plan to toggle the input section of the wellpanel.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the question right, but why are you using `justify-content: space-between`? It's the reason why section 2 appears on the right hand side of the panel, in particular you can delete it and section 2 will appear next to section 1.

Comment: @Jan Your suggestion worked. I had googled the code and didn't really understand what the ```justify-content: space-between``` was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Removing the `justify-content: space-between` fixed the issue.